# docker doesn't get the latest images with tag latest

Tags: jenkins, docker

in my Dockerfile i have

```
FROM jenkins:latest
```

When I used it to build an image i've got some version from that moment (1.642.5). 
Now months later i want to rebuild the image with an updated jenkins version. 
I dropped (docker rmi) the image and rebuild (even with --no-cache=true) but still that old version is used instead of the latest 1.651.3

Now i've specified the correct version

```
FROM jenkins:1.651.3
```

and now the 'latest' is being downloaded and used.

Is this normal behaviour or a fault with the 'latest' tag at jenkins docker hub?
https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

Regards,

jr00n

Answer (score 2):

The reason your Dockerfile was using "elder" version was because once you had downloaded `jenkins:latest` image on your machine it was using its cached version every time you tried to build your own image. The `--no-cache` option means that your image will be build without using cache from already-built layers, but it will still use the "cache" from the base image.

If you wanted it to work properly you should either remove the base image - `jenkins:latest` or use `--pull` option when building.